# Read file, multiple lines at a time (separated by delimiter)

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, bibtex

I have a large collection of .bib BibTeX entries saved in a single file. I want to read the file, store the data of each article (essentially separated by `@`) into a variable, extract specific fields, and finally output the fields (tab-separated) into a cleaned-up file.

Input:

```
@article{Author1_2020,
    year = 2020,
    month = {feb},
    publisher = {Wiley},
    ...
}
@article{Author2_2010,
    year = 2010,
    month = {jul},
    publisher = {Journal},
    ...
}
```

Output:

```
Wiley   2020    feb
Journal 2010    jul
```

Code:

````sh
while IFS='@' read -r entry; do
    p=$(grep "publisher =" <<< "$entry" | cut ...)
    y=$(grep "year =" <<< "$entry" | awk ...)
    m=$(grep "month =" <<< "$entry" | cut ...)
    echo "$p    $y  $m" >> cleaned_up.bib
done < global.bib
```sh

Is there a way to make the `while read` command in bash operate on delimited chunks of text at a time, instead of single lines? `sed`/`awk` solutions would be more than welcome.
````

Comment: IIRC there was a bibtex parser available for python, why don't you use that instead? Writing a parser in shell language would be reinventing the wheel.

Comment: This probably answer your question: \[ _tex.stackexchange.com_ \] [Command line tool to extract .bib entry by key](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81925/command-line-tool-to-extract-bib-entry-by-key)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach with `awk` that should be portable across all `awk` varieties can use `'='` as the field-separator, e.g.:

```
awk -F= '
    $1~/[ ]*year/       { year = substr($2,2,match($2,/,/)-2) }
    $1~/[ ]*month/      { month = substr($2,3,match($2,/,/)-4) }
    $1~/[ ]*publisher/  { pub = substr($2,3,match($2,/,/)-4) }
    FNR>1 && $1~/^@/    { print pub"\t"year"\t"month }
    END                 { print pub"\t"year"\t"month }
' list.bib
```

Where each of the rules extracts either the `year`, `month` or `publisher` and trims the additional characters from either end of the wanted string using `substr()` and `match()`. The `END` rule is used to print the final set of values collected.

**Example Use/Output**

With your example data in `list.bib`, executing the command would result in:

```
awk -F= '
    $1~/[ ]*year/       { year = substr($2,2,match($2,/,/)-2) }
    $1~/[ ]*month/      { month = substr($2,3,match($2,/,/)-4) }
    $1~/[ ]*publisher/  { pub = substr($2,3,match($2,/,/)-4) }
    FNR>1 && $1~/^@/    { print pub"\t"year"\t"month }
    END                 { print pub"\t"year"\t"month }
' list.bib
Wiley   2020    feb
Journal 2010    jul
```

Comment: I chose this answer because it's quite clear what's going on in each line, with the basic familiarity of awk that I have. This command is also easy to modify/expand (e.g. to include more fields, change column order).

Comment: How can I get the last word from the output of `substr($2,3,match($2,/,/)-4)`? This is for an 'author' field. I'm not sure how to incorporate the typical `{print $NF}` command into this sequence.

Comment: Don't use `=` as the FS or it'll fail when any of the data strings contain an =, eg. given a line in one of the blocks like `title = {foo = bar}`. When faced with tag=value data, do `tag=val=$0; sub(/[[:space:]]*=.*/,"",tag); sub(/[^=]+=[[:space:]]*/,"",val)` instead to guarantee only the first = will be treated as the separator and neither the tag nor the value will be corrupted.  You'll also have problems with your script if any of the values can contain a comma, e.g. `publisher = {O'Reilley, Ltd.}`

Comment: OOh many thanks Ed. I considered the uniqueness of `'='` here, and did have to assume there were no more in the `{...}` field that followed. The use of `sub` is noted and would be superior. (I actually asked myself "What would Ed do..." and I did recall your use of `sub` instead of using `substr()`, but my thinking was locked at that point `:)`

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk:

```
awk '{print $17, $6, $11}' RS='}\n' FS='( +|{|}|,)' OFS='\t' global.bib
```

Output:

```
Wiley   2020    feb
Journal 2010    jul
```

I set the input record separator (`RS`) to `}` followed by a newline. Default is a newline.

The input field separator (`FS`) I set to at least one space ( `+`) or `{` or `}` or `,`. `OFS` is the output field separator.

A different notation with the same output:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="}\n"; FS="( +|{|}|,)"; OFS="\t"} {print $17, $6, $11}' global.bib
```

Comment: What do `$17` and so on refer to?

Comment: In the first block `$17` (17th column) refers to `Wiley` (with `FS='( +|{|}|,)'`).

Comment: See: `awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) print "column:",i,$i}' RS='}\n' FS='( +|{|}|,)' OFS='\t'  global.bib` `NF` is number of last column.

Comment: I you modify the field separator (`FS`) it becomes much clearer: `awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) print "column:",i,$i}' RS='}\n' FS='(\n?@article{|\n    | = {?|}?,?\n    )' OFS='\t' global.bib`

Comment: The `FS` in the answer is relying on undefined behavior since `{` is the start of a repetition (an RE-interval specification like `a{3}`) and so its meaning is undefined when it's not preceded by an  expression to repeat. You need to change `|{` to `|[{]` to make it robust and portable (not so much of an issue since you said it was gawk-only anyway). You have problems if any of the fields contain blanks or commas anyway though, e.g. `publisher = {Sue and Bob, Ltd.}`

Answer (score 2):

Whenever the input data has tag-value pairs I find it best to first create an array of that mapping (`f[]` below) and then you can print whatever fields you like in whatever order you like by their tags (names):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    OFS="\t"
    numTags = split(flds,tags)
}
/^}/ {
    for (tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++) {
        tag = tags[tagNr]
        printf "%s%s", f[tag], (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
    }
    delete f
    next
}
{
    gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:],]+$/,"")
    tag = val = $0
    if ( sub(/^@/,"",tag) ) {
        sub(/\{.*/,"",tag)
        sub(/[^{]+\{|/,"",val)
    }
    else {
        sub(/[[:space:]]*=.*/,"",tag)
        sub(/[^=]+=[[:space:]]*/,"",val)
        gsub(/^\{|\}$/,"",val)
    }
    f[tag] = val
}
```

.

```
$ awk -v flds='publisher year month' -f tst.awk file
Wiley   2020    feb
Journal 2010    jul
```

.

```
$ awk -v flds='month year article publisher' -f tst.awk file
feb     2020    Author1_2020    Wiley
jul     2010    Author2_2010    Journal
```

Given the above approach you can trivially add comparisons to the code inside the `/^}/ { ... }` block such as

```
if ( (f["publisher"] == "Wiley") && (f["year"] == 2020) ) {
    do whatever you like
}
```

or you can tweak it so just convert your input to a CSV or JSON or any other format you like for output.

Comment: I like this answer quite a lot. I would like to obtain only the last word for a specific tag (`author = {John Ford and James Smith and ... and Tom Williams} -> Williams`). I have an idea of how to do this with a subsequent sed command, but how can I achieve this in the same awk block?

Comment: `sub(/.* /,"",f["author"])`

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `ed` and `column`

Given the file `global.bib`

```
@article{Author1_2020,
    year = 2020,
    month = {feb},
    publisher = {Wiley},
    mama = {foo},
    papa = {bar},
}
@article{Author2_2010,
    year = 2010,
    month = {jul},
    publisher = {Journal},
    mama = {foo},
    papa = {bar},
}
@article{Author3_2010,
    year = 2010,
    month = {aug},
    publisher = {Josh},
    mama = {foo},
    papa = {bar},
}
@article{Author4_2030,
    year = 2030,
    month = {dec},
    publisher = {Jetchisel},
    mama = {foo},
    blah = {qux},
    papa = {bar},
}
```

---

The `ed` script, let's just call it `script.ed`

```
g/./s/^@.*//\
s/^}.*//
v/^.*publisher =.*$\|^.*year =.*$\|^.*month =.*$\|^$/d
,s/^.*publisher = \|^.*year = \|^.*month = //
g/./s/}//\
s/{//\
s/,//
g/./s/$/ /
g/./;/^$/j
,s/\([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\)/\3 \1 \2/
g/^$/d
,p
Q
```

---

Now run the `ed` script against the file and pipe it to column with the `-t` flag.

```sh
ed -s global.bib < script.ed | column -t
```

---

The output

```
Wiley      2020  feb
Journal    2010  jul
Josh       2010  aug
Jetchisel  2030  dec
```

---

A brief explanation.

- lines 1 and 2, search the whole file `g` means global, replace all lines that starts with a `@` and a `}` with nothing, make it an empty line.
- The `\` is a line continuation. so line 1 and 2 is just one, separated by a new line.
- line 3, the  `v` means the opposite of whatever is matched inside the `/ /`, in this case `publisher`, `year`, and `month` plus an empty/blank line, delete it, the `d` means delete.
- line 4, `,s` is also global an alternative for `g`. remove whatever is inside the `/ /`, not delete the lines that contain it just remove it.
- line 5  to 7 is also connected, there is a trailining `\`, remove all that is matched inside the `/ /`, which is `{`, `}` and `,`
- line 8 add a trailing space on the file.
- line 9 , join a non-empty line starts from the beginning of the file, `g` for global, until it hits an empty line.
- line 10 , back reference all the fields, and print them according to the order needed.
- line 11 delete all empty/blank lines.
- line 12 `,p` print all the output to stdout.
- line 13, `Q` quit ed without an error even if the buffer is modified, change it to `w` if in-place editing of the file is needed.
- You can run the ed script line by line just include all lines that is separated by a `\` and the next line after it, because it's just one ed invocation.

---

With `bash4+` `grep` and `column`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

limit=3

while mapfile -n "$limit" -t array; (( ${#array[*]} )); do
  array=("${array[@]//[\}\{,]}")
  array=("${array[@]#*= }")
  printf '%s %s %s\n' "${array[2]}" "${array[0]}" "${array[1]}"
done < <(
  grep -E '^[[:space:]]*(publisher|year|month) = ' global.bib
) | column -t
```

Comment: Whoa.... that is certainly an involved `ed` script. A for effort and persistence `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, it is a bit confusing at first but if you'll get the hang of it, for me `awk` is a bit hard than `ed` :-)

Comment: I'll have to learn `ed`, because for me, it is just the opposite. I look at `ed` and my eyes roll back in my head, but with `awk` I can usually muddle through `:)`

Comment: I need to do the opposite, since `awk` is very good for text manipulation.

Comment: It would not take you long to become really proficient. The mental hurdle to get over is the use of the field and record separators  that determine the delimiters that will be used. Then, like `ed` it is just one rule per-line that will be applied to each input record (line). The rules are thankfully written in a straight-forward procedural syntax similar to C. I found [GNU Awk Users Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents) very helpful, especially *9.1.3 String-Manipulation Functions*. It also tells you what are GNU extensions to `awk`.

Comment: @Jetchisel the awk language is essentially just a tiny subset of C (or whatever other Algol-base language you like) optimized to ONLY do text-processing wrapped in an implicit while-read loop that splits each input line/record into fields. Once you get used to that paradigm the syntax is trivial as there's literally only about a dozen built in functions plus the usual comparison operators we all know and love. The shocking thing is how powerful the tool/language is given that.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk :

```
awk 'match($0, /\s*(\S+)\s*=\s*\{?([^},]*)/, a) { r[a[1]]=a[2] }
     /^\}$/ { print r["publisher"], r["year"], r["month"] }
    ' OFS='\t' global.bib
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^@/{:a;N;/^}/M!ba;s/.*year = \(....\).*month = {\(...\)}.*publisher = {\([^}]*\)}.*/\3\t\1\t\2/}' file
```

Gather up lines between one starting with `@` and another starting with `}`.

Use pattern matching to extract the required fields and tab separate the result.

N.B. Use the `M` flag on the multiline regexp as the lines are gathered up in the pattern space.